# How to add multiple inputs in specific cell or table's td?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

I have one table, in which I want to add multiple inputs filed in the 3rd column of 1st row.
if I click on add pk1 button it's not get added into the specific td that is `<td class=partition1>` any solution using jQuery or Javascript? inputs must be added in the display:block mode not in inline mode.
which is the easiest way to handle this using Jquery or javascript?

```js
$('.add-pkey1').on('click','.partition1' ,function(){
var t0 = $('.partition1').append('<input type="text" name="input1" value="test" />');
            $('#table-id').append(t0);

})
```

```css
 table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 1em;
}

thead {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

td,
th {
    border: solid grey 1px;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table
          id="table-id" 
        >
          <thead >
            <tr>
              <th colspan="6" class="text-center">
                <span>Source : </span>
              </th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <th>input1</th>
              <th>input2</th>
              <th class="partition1">Partition1</th>
              <th class="partition2">
                Partition2
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input
                  id="input1"
                  type="text"
                  name="input1"
                />
              </td>
              <td>
                <input
                  id="input2"
                  type="text"
                  name="input2"
                />
              </td>
              <td class="partition1">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="partition"    
                  />
              </td>
              <td class="partition2">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="partition2"
                />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
<button class="add-pkey1">add pk1</button>
```

JsFiddle : - https://jsfiddle.net/shreekantbatale2/zfus24m9/1/

Comment: Typo, your class selectors are missing their `.` on the front to denote that they are classes.

Comment: still not working @Taplar

Comment: Then please update your question with your class fix to show what you are working with currently

Comment: @Taplar now check

Comment: Ok, so lets examine the logic.  You're making a delegate event binding on the add-pkey1 button, which then catches the click event for any child that has the class of `partition1` on it.  Which, that button does not have any children with that class.  So that's not goin gto work.  But lets ignore that error.  Lets say it did work and it found a child.  You then select all elements with a class of `partition1` which are a `th` and a `td` element.  You then append an input field, which would put it in both the header and cell.  Seems like another error.  Ignorning that error ...

Comment: ... you would then append `t0` to the table, which would try to append both the th and td to the table element, which th and td cannot be direct children of a table.  So that is a third error.

Comment: @Taplar I'm Confused!

Comment: I pretty much spelled out the issues.  What are you confused about?

Comment: how to solve this issue @Taplar

Comment: You need to examine each one of those issues, and solve them one at a time.  Break your problem down into smaller parts.  For each one of those issues, understand why it is an issue, determine what you actually want the logic to do, and then figure out how to write that logic.

Comment: okay @Taplar Thanks will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Taplar said earlier there are multiple issues with your code, so I won't get into them one by one. But I will mention the notable ones.

- `.on()` will **accept an event, selector, data, and handler, but in your case you just need two of them** so it should be `.on('click', function(){})` instead of the current version.
- In order to add an element to your third column, all you need to do is, get the element-specific class or id and append the desired element into it. But **what did you do there will cause to append another `<th>` to your table so it means it will automatically add the new element to a new row and will break the table** structure since there are 4 columns and you want to add `<th>` between column 3 and 4.
- **`partition1` is not a unique class in your HTML** so whenever you try to add something to it, it will add in two different places.

Here is a fix for you looking for:

```js
$('.add-pkey1').on('click', function() {
  $('.partition1.column3').append('<input type="text" name="input1" value="test" />');
})
```

```css
 table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 1em;
}

thead {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

td,
th {
    border: solid grey 1px;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table-id">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6" class="text-center">
        <span>Source : </span>
      </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>input1</th>
      <th>input2</th>
      <th class="partition1">Partition1</th>
      <th class="partition2">
        Partition2
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="input1" type="text" name="input1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input2" type="text" name="input2" />
      </td>
      <td class="partition1 column3">
        <input type="text" name="partition" />
      </td>
      <td class="partition2">
        <input type="text" name="partition2" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button class="add-pkey1">add pk1</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation in the easiest way! :)